# BinaryFormatter and changed type of Property

Tags: c#, serialization, back, binaryformatter

We have to change one of our Properties from nullable integer to string.
After the change in the class we get the exception:

> Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.String'.

We deserialize the objects with this code:

```
byte[] o =GetByteArray();
var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var memStream = new MemoryStream(o);
var obj = binFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
```

What would the easiest way to work with old objects?

Comment: Create a new type instead of changing the old.

Comment: There is no easy way, you need to create a new class.  It is not obvious from the question how you are going to convert old Foo objects to Foov2, you'll have to think about it.

Comment: Unfortunately we have millions of files with the old structure. It wouldn't be really easy to create a new class.

Comment: It is just one class, not millions.  Focus on the real problem, you have to make hay of old data that doesn't have that string.

Comment: Well, actually this is not only one class. The class has other class as properties with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try a custom property :

```
   public class MyClass
    {
        private string myString { get; set; }

        public int MyInt
        {
            get { return int.Parse(myString); }
            set { myString = value.ToString(); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. We would like to stay with the old name. There are many applications which use this field. (the type is not important for them)

Comment: @user278618, if type is not important, why change it? You can add a proxy property like in this answer, mark in as non-serializable and just use for sources that require new type.

Comment: One component get data from database and then fill the object with those data and then serialize the object.Other applications read the file deserialize it and use it for view. That is the only place, where the type is not important.Instead of introducting in every application a new field we want to change change only the place where we deserialize the data.